# Cursor goes to end after setting text to UITextField inside shouldChangeCharactersIn

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

I have text label which has phone number in it. I mask the phone number when user is typing so that in `shouldChangeCharactersIn` function;

- I get user input (string)
- Add that input to text which is already written in `UITextField`
- Mask text and set it to `UITextField`
- Return false

My question is that after I set text of `UITextfield` (delete or add new character `UITextField`, cursor moves to the end but I want it to stay in the same position. (By meaning same position, I mean same when I don't implement `shouldChangeCharactersIn` function) How can I do that? Thank you.

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {

    guard CharacterSet(charactersIn: "0123456789").isSuperset(of: CharacterSet(charactersIn: string)) else {
        return false
    }
    if let text = textField.text {
        let newLength = text.count + string.count - range.length
        let newText = text + string

        let textFieldText: NSString = (textField.text ?? "") as NSString
        let txtAfterUpdate = textFieldText.replacingCharacters(in: range, with: string)
            if(newLength <= 15){
                //textField.text = txtAfterUpdate
                textField.text = txtAfterUpdate.digits.applyPatternOnNumbers()
                return false
            }
            return newLength <= 15
    }
    return true
}
```

Mask Function:

```
func applyPatternOnNumbers(pattern: String = "(###) ### ## ##", replacmentCharacter: Character = "#") -> String {
var pureNumber = self.replacingOccurrences( of: "[^0-9]", with: "", options: .regularExpression)
for index in 0 ..< pattern.count {
    guard index < pureNumber.count else { return pureNumber }
    let stringIndex = String.Index(encodedOffset: index)
    let patternCharacter = pattern[stringIndex]
    guard patternCharacter != replacmentCharacter else { continue }
    pureNumber.insert(patternCharacter, at: stringIndex)
}
return pureNumber
}
```

What I want in GIF

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {

        guard CharacterSet(charactersIn: "0123456789").isSuperset(of: CharacterSet(charactersIn: string)) else {
            return false
        }
        if let text = textField.text {
            let newLength = text.count + string.count - range.length
            let newText = text + string

            let textFieldText: NSString = (textField.text ?? "") as NSString
            let txtAfterUpdate = textFieldText.replacingCharacters(in: range, with: string)
            if(newLength <= 15){

                var currentPosition = 0
                if let selectedRange = textField.selectedTextRange {
                    currentPosition = textField.offset(from: textField.beginningOfDocument, to: selectedRange.start)
                }

                if(string == ""){
                    if(currentPosition == 2){
                        if(textField.text!.count > 2){
                            currentPosition = 1
                        }else{
                            currentPosition = 0
                        }
                    }else if(currentPosition == 7){
                        currentPosition = 4
                    }else if(currentPosition == 11){
                        currentPosition = 9
                    }else if(currentPosition == 14){
                        currentPosition = 12
                    }else{
                        if(currentPosition != 1){
                            currentPosition = currentPosition - 1
                        }
                    }
                }else{
                    if(currentPosition == 0){
                        currentPosition = 2
                    }else if(currentPosition == 4){
                        currentPosition = 7
                    }else if(currentPosition == 9){
                        currentPosition = 11
                    }else if(currentPosition == 12){
                        currentPosition = 14
                    }else{
                        currentPosition = currentPosition + 1
                    }
                }

                textField.text = txtAfterUpdate.applyPatternOnNumbers()
                print("textField Length -> : \(textField.text?.count ?? 0)")

                    if let newPosition = textField.position(from: textField.beginningOfDocument, offset: currentPosition) {
                        textField.selectedTextRange = textField.textRange(from: newPosition, to: newPosition)
                    }

                return false
            }
            return newLength <= 15
        }
        return true
    }
```

Comment: @Emre Önder check it May be help you

Comment: When I make it return true, It adds additional character because we already set new text with textField.text =

Comment: @EmreÖnder Check my updated code. it will be work as par you want. Thanks.

Comment: This doesn't mask the phone Number?

Comment: @EmreÖnder please check one more time it will be done

Comment: Cursor stay behind the last number after mask function is working. Did you try the code? Can you please share a gif or smth?

Comment: Yes i was try it   bt now i am not Office so tomorrow i shall be   share proper explanation

Comment: It work better i was try all cases which possibly bt no one do anything bed.

Comment: @EmreÖnder hello dear. I have check this code and get some major issue  Now it was fixed so test in your code and give me confirmation

Comment: @EmreÖnder Thank you.

Comment: Can you please try to delete two number from somewhere center and write two number instead of deleted ones? Cursor goes end after you write one character, so the second number will be written to end of textfield.

Comment: @EmreÖnder check my updated code.  It will be your final testing. Thank you.

Comment: I'll check it and let u know. Thank you for your effort.

Comment: Can you please try to delete two number from somewhere center and write two number instead of deleted ones? Cursor goes end after you write one character, so the second number will be written to end of textfield  :--- Also tested this case.

Comment: @EmreÖnder okey.

Comment: Sorry I'm not at the office right now. I can check it later

Comment: No problem i ll wait for your updation Thank you.

Comment: @TmGoyani thank you so much it's working like charm i had the same requirement , you rock :)

Comment: Works like a charm! Thank you.

Comment: @TmGoyani can you help me with this answer too : https://stackoverflow.com/q/53440489/2714877